# tkinter OptionMenu in combination with trace throws "TclError: No more menus can be allocated"

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

I want to write a code generator in python and asking the user to select by an ttk.OptionMenu the type of variable. Right behind this OptionMenu the user has to define the value inside a ttk.Checkbutton if it is a boolean type or an entry if it is an integer or string and define a value. The GUI looks like the following:

[image]

If I want to change the type to int or string the **ttk.Checkbutton** in behind should change to an **ttk.Entry**, but the program does crash because it can't allocate any more menus [**_tkinter.TclError: No more menus can be allocated.**]. I dont know what to do and found no solution. I am connecting my checkbutton by trace with a function that gets called all the time the optionmenu has changed.

Here is my simple coding example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from functools import partial


class MyWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        line = [tk.StringVar(value="bool"), tk.BooleanVar(value=True)]
        self.vars = [line]
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        for widget in self.children.values():
            widget.grid_forget()
        x = 0
        for var in self.vars:
            ttk.OptionMenu(self, var[0], var[0].get(), *["bool", "int", "string"]).grid(row=x, column=0)
            var[0].trace("w", partial(self.menu_changed, line=var))
            if var[0].get() == "bool":
                ttk.Checkbutton(self, variable=var[1].get()).grid(row=x, column=1)
            else:
                ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=var[1].get()).grid(row=x, column=1)
            x += 1
        ttk.Button(self, text="+", command=self.add, width=3).grid(row=x, column=0)
        self.place(x=10, y=10, anchor=tk.NW)

    def add(self):
        line = [tk.StringVar(value="bool"), tk.BooleanVar(value=True)]
        self.vars.append(line)
        self.show()

    def menu_changed(self, *_, line):
        if line[0].get() == "bool":
            line[1] = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        elif line[0].get() == "int":
            line[1] = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        elif line[0].get() == "string":
            line[1] = tk.StringVar()
        self.show()


root = tk.Tk()
window = MyWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I hope you do have any idea what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two major problems in your code. The first is that you keep making new widgets every time `self.show()` or `self.menu_changed()` is called, the second is that you set the tracing of the variable inside your `self.show()` function, which is therefore executed many times.

I rearranged your code, only creating new widgets and setting the trace in the `self.add()` function. This way you don't create more widgets than necessary. The only "problem" with this is that I use a `StringVar` for the Checkbutton/Entry even when you have a Boolean or Integer selected, so all values are converted to strings. I also added a print button to print out all current values.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from functools import partial


class MyWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lines = []
        self.add_button = ttk.Button(self, text="+", command=self.add, width=3)
        self.print_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Print", command=self.print_values)
        self.place(x=10, y=10, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.add()

    def show(self):
        for widget in self.children.values():
            widget.grid_forget()
        x = 0
        for line in self.lines:
            line[2].grid(row=x, column=0)
            if line[0].get() == "bool":
                line[3].grid(row=x, column=1)
            else:
                line[4].grid(row=x, column=1)
            x += 1
        self.add_button.grid(row=x, column=0)
        self.print_button.grid(row=x, column=1)

    def add(self):
        line = [tk.StringVar(value="bool"), tk.StringVar(value="1")]
        line.append(ttk.OptionMenu(self, line[0], line[0].get(), *["bool", "int", "string"]))
        line.append(ttk.Checkbutton(self, variable=line[1]))
        line.append(ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=line[1]))
        line[0].trace("w", partial(self.menu_changed, line=line))
        self.lines.append(line)
        self.show()

    def menu_changed(self, *_, line):
        if line[0].get() == "bool":
            line[1].set("1")
        elif line[0].get() == "int":
            line[1].set("0")
        elif line[0].get() == "string":
            line[1].set("")
        self.show()

    def print_values(self):
        print("Current values:")
        for line in self.lines:
            print(line[1].get())


root = tk.Tk()
window = MyWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

By the way, you don't really need to trace the StringVar, you can add a command parameter to the OptionMenu like:

```
ttk.OptionMenu(self, line[0], line[0].get(), *["bool", "int", "string"], command=partial(self.menu_changed, line=line))
```

Answer (score 0):

By the help of the previous answer from @fhdrsdg I have found the mistake. I have written ...

```
ttk.OptionMenu(self, var[0], var[0].get(), *["bool", "int", "string"]).grid(row=x, column=0)
var[0].trace("w", partial(self.menu_changed, line=var))
```

... and did grid(...) before doing trace(...)

If you write the following instead and put the command inside the declaration of the optionmenu its getting traced before grid() and works. Here is the working line of code:

```
cmd = partial(self.menu_changed, line=var)
ttk.OptionMenu(self, var[0], var[0].get(), *["bool", "int", "string"], command=cmd).grid(row=x, column=0)
```

But many thanks @fhdrsdg because I would have never found this mistake without his hint.

Comment: If that's the only thing you're going to take from my answer, you're still going to have a bad time. You keep making way too many widgets, just at a less extreme rate. Also, using the `command` parameter is not the same as tracing a variable, the trace fires every time the variable value changes, the command fires every time an option in the OptionMenu is selected. It's just that both work for your intended use. The problem is not that you're using trace, it's that your're using it inside the `show()` function.

Comment: @fhdrsdg you are right your example is great but for me it is not useful because my code is much more complex and to change it the way you describe does not fulfill all my requirements. That way it is working even with 10 option menus. And that is enough for my purpose.

Comment: I understand. Whether it's worth the effort to rewrite your code is something only you can decide. I just hope you understand my concerns and keep it in mind for any future projects. Good luck!

Comment: @fhdrsdg yes I understand and your solution is quite well but for me to complicated to change the whole code. But in future I will remind it. Thank you!